# [C++]Finding error about the pointer of a distribution (function)

Tags: c++, function, pointers, random

Could someone tell me what is wrong about my code (C++):

```
int main(){
unsigned seed = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
std::subtract_with_carry_engine<unsigned, 24, 10, 24> gen(seed);
std::tr1::normal_distribution<double> *imDensity;
imDensity = new std::tr1::normal_distribution<double>(0, 5);

double p = imDensity(gen) //here is the error
}
```

The error is "expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type". I have to pass the random generator to the distribution function, but I don't know how to do it when using a pointer.

Comment: What is the error please?

Comment: @RichardGeorge "expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`imDensity` is a pointer but there really is no reason for it to be, as it is just slower and easier to leak memory. But if you must use a pointer, try `(*imDensity)(gen)`

Comment: Thank you, (*imDensity)(gen) works, and also for your advice.